# What is Sentinel lymph node?

Tags: breast, metastatic-cancer, lymph-nodes

The axillary lymph node group does not include the sentinel lymph node and [Wikipedia says](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_lymph_node) it is a “hypothetical ” lymph node which is the first to be drained by a tumour. It also has a significant role in diagnosis of breast cancer. [Thieme atlas of anatomy][2]

My questions

1) Is sentinel lymph node actually present? If yes why is it not included in axillary lymph node group?

2)How do they affect metastasise?

Comment: You seem to not understand what the word "hypothetical" means. It means the node doesn't physically exist. A sentinel lymph node can be any lymph node in the body. It's a term used to refer to the first lymph node that receives drainage from the area of a tumor, wherever that tumor might be.